# Letterspacing in a colorbox in beamer

Tags: beamer, kerning

Preparing a `beamer` presentation with my own template, I wanted to change for a single slide that the foot line gets a white background (because I have a graphic that exceeds the margins). So I changed the `text in foot` beamer template (which is called by the `footline` template) to wrap everything within a `colorbox`. After compiling I saw that the the foot line on this slide has a different inter-letter spacing than all the other slides.

Reducing the document to a minimum code that still reproduces this feature, I found that the `helvet` package, a `beamercolorbox` and the `colorbox` seem to be necessary. So here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=1ex]{text in head/foot}
        \usebeamertemplate{text in foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{text in foot}{
    \insertshortauthor~~--~~Page~\insertframenumber
}

\author{My Name}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\bgroup
\setbeamertemplate{text in foot}{\hspace*{-0.5\fboxsep}\colorbox{white}{%
    \insertshortauthor~~--~~Page~\insertframenumber
}}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

What you see is that the distance between M and y, or N and a is different on the two slides. So here is my question:

- What causes this difference?
- Which of the two versions is "right", i.e. properly typeset?

Comment: I see no difference (when I compile it myself). Are you sure it's not just a screen artifact? BTW, it's the kerning, not letterspacing, that is different - letterspacing would apply to all inter-letter spaces.

Comment: I tested it with different zooms and more than just two slides. It is always only the slides with the additional colorbox that have the different kerning.

Comment: I agree with @Robert - compiling with pdflatex from texlive2017 I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply change the colour?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{helvet}

\setbeamercolor{text in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[dp=1ex, ht=2ex]{text in head/foot}%
        \usebeamertemplate{text in foot}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{text in foot}{%
    ~\insertshortauthor~~--~~Page~\insertframenumber%
}

\author{My Name}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\bgroup
\setbeamercolor{text in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=red}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sure, that is the better way of doing this (and I will in the end, but that will require some more work in my actual template). However, this doesn't answer _why _ the letterspacing is different and _which_ of the two versions has the proper typesetting.